# How to setup Narayana ConnectionManager so it doesn't stop after some transactions

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, transactionmanager

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Session and JTA Narayana (arjuna), I'm sending select and insert statements in a loop using two different threads.

The application runs correctly for some time but after some number of transactions, the Arjuna ConnectionManager fails to get a connection and generates the following exception:

```
2019-10-05 22:48:20.724  INFO 27032 --- [o-auto-1-exec-4] c.m.m.db.PrepareStatementExec            : START select
2019-10-05 22:49:20.225  WARN 27032 --- [nsaction Reaper] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna                    : ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a82101:c116:5d989ef0:6e in state  RUN
2019-10-05 22:49:20.228  WARN 27032 --- [Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna                    : ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffc0a82101:c116:5d989ef0:6e invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2019-10-05 22:49:20.234  WARN 27032 --- [Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna                    : ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffc0a82101:c116:5d989ef0:6e completed with multiple threads - thread http-nio-auto-1-exec-10 was in progress with java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jdbc.ConnectionManager.create(ConnectionManager.java:134)
com.arjuna.ats.jdbc.TransactionalDriver.connect(TransactionalDriver.java:89)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
com.mono.multidatasourcetest.db.PrepareStatementExec.executeUpdate(PrepareStatementExec.java:51)
```

Source code is in github https://github.com/saavedrah/multidataset-test

I'm wondering if the connection should be closed or if I should change some settings in Arjuna to make the ConnectionManager work.

Answer (score 0):

although what you are showing is a stack trace being printed by the Narayana BasicAction class (rather than an exception) the result for you is ultimately the same and you need to close your connections.

You should most likely look to add it in close to the same place you are doing the getConnection calls within https://github.com/saavedrah/multidataset-test/blob/cf910c345db079a4e910a071ac0690af28bd3f81/src/main/java/com/mono/multidatasourcetest/db/PrepareStatementExec.java#L38

e.g.

```
//connection = getConnection
//do something with it
//connection.close()
```

But as Connection is AutoCloseable you could just do:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection) {
    connnection.doSomething();
}
```